# Why my Hypoestes phyllostachya Baker is drying?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations

I've noticed that after a month or so since buying, leaves of my Hypoestes phyllostachya is becoming brown and then dry out and colors are somewhat fading. I keep it in front of a south side window, that is a little bit open and shady. The weather is cold here.I water it whenever the soil gets dried, every week or 10 day. What do you recommend?[image: there she is]

Hi again, as you can see in these photos they lost so many leaves during this year, I don't know what's wrong, they continue to grow vertically with just two or three leaves at the top, and while having new leaves, the older ones start drying out.
I kept them in shadow and their soil moisture. Can anybody help please?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://www.thespruce.com/grow-hypoestes-phyllostachya-indoors-1902650), you should keep the soil moist during the growing season.  Perhaps you're letting it dry out a bit too much.